# Doing math with Time using js

Tags: javascript, html, input, time

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>
            Page Time
            <input id="pageTime" name="pageTime" type="time" step="1" tabindex="9">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>
            Ack Time
            <input id="ackTime" name="ackTime" type="time" step="1" tabindex="10">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>
            Arrival Time
            <input id="arrivalTime" name="arrivalTime" type="time" step="1" tabindex="11">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>
            Start Replace / Root Cause Found
            <input id="startReplace" name="startReplace" type="time" step="1" tabindex="12">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <label>
            Replaced / Repair Completed
            <input id="replaced" name="replaced" type="time" step="1" tabindex="13">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <label>
            Engagement
            <input type="text" id="engagement" name="engagement" value="" readonly="readonly" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <label>
            Arrival
            <input type="text" id="arrival" name="arrival" value="" readonly="readonly" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <label>
            Investigation
            <input type="text" id="investigation" name="investigation" value="" readonly="readonly" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <label>
            Mitigate
            <input type="text" id="mitigate" name="mitigate" value="" readonly="readonly" />
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1" style="text-align: center">
        <label>
            Total Ops Phases
            <input type="text" name="totalOpsPhases" id="totalOpsPhases" value="" readonly="readonly" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-submit">
        <button class="submitbtn" tabindex="14" onclick="opsTime();">Do the Math</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function toSeconds(time_str) {
    // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
    var parts = time_str.split(':');
    var sum = 0;
    // compute  and return total seconds
    for (c = 0; c <= 2; c++) {
        if (c === 0) {
            sum += parts[0] * 3600;
        } else if (c === 1) {
            sum += parts[1] * 60;
        } else if (c === 2) {
            if (parts[2] !== 'undefined') {
                sum += parts[2];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
function opsTime() {
    var time = [document.getElementById('pageTime').value, document.getElementById('ackTime').value, document.getElementById('arrivalTime').value, document.getElementById('startReplace').value, document.getElementById('replaced').value];
    // Created an array to easily do the math :)
    // Array mapping:
    // 0 = pageTime
    // 1 = ackTime
    // 2 = arrivalTime
    // 3 = startReplaceTime
    // 4 = replacedTime

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (i === 4) {
            var start = time[0];
            var end = time[4];
        } else {
            start = time[i];
            end = time[i + 1];
        }
        var startSec = toSeconds(start);
        var endSec = toSeconds(end);
        var difference = Math.abs(endSec - startSec);
        // format time differnece
        var result = [
            Math.floor(difference / 3600), // an hour has 3600 seconds
            Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60), // a minute has 60 seconds
            difference % 60
        ];
        // 0 padding and concatation
        result = result.map(function (v) {
            return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
        }).join(':');
        var res = [];
        res[i] = result;
    }

    document.getElementById('engagement').value = res[0];
    document.getElementById('arrival').value = res[1];
    document.getElementById('investigation').value = res[2];
    document.getElementById('mitigate').value = res[3];
    document.getElementById('totalOpsPhase').value = res[4];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to pick the times filled in the inputs and show the difference in the inputs boxes below.

- Engagement should be the time difference between Page Time and Ack Time;
- Arrival should be the time difference between Ack Time and Arrival Time;
- Investigation should be the time difference between Arrival and Start Replace Time;
- Mitigate should be the time difference between Start Replace and Replaced time;
- Total Ops Phases should be the time difference between Replaced and Page time.

I'm stuck on the code above for almost 8 hours, changed a lot of things trying to do the math and put each time difference inside an array and then use it to fill the inputs, but it seems the array isn't get filled with data.
Unfortunately I have to use the seconds as well, and I couldn't find much material with different solutions to calculate the difference of times using it.

I will be glad if someone can see another way to solve this matter.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Tried to insert a print of the form but I don't have the reputation needed.

Comment: Perhaps [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) will help ?

Comment: Cool stuff, didn't know. Will give it a try, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type="time"` attribute is only supported by chrome, not Firefox or Internet Explorer so you should be using a compatibility library like [these](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/) or one of your own making. If you just want to use chrome you can use valueAsNumber:

```
v.valueAsNumber
56013000
v.valueAsDate
Thu Jan 01 1970 10:33:33 GMT-0500 (EST)
v.value
"15:33:33"
```

Note that the Chrome [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) will show you these options with auto suggest.

Also [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4dg10e7/)

Comment: I hadn't noticed that this attribute is not supported by Firefox and IE. Thanks for pointing this out! I will try Vaverke's solution in first instance as it seems to be cleaner and easier to manipulate, but your solution seems to work as well. Appreciate the help!

Comment: The libraries are interesting I will take a deeper look, thanks again!